# SQL to filter table with similar value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these data in table1

```
table1
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
  A       B       C       D
  A       B       G       F
  A       B       C       G
  G       B       C       F
  A       B       C       H
```

I am trying to create a sql statment such that search for same value in ColB and then same value in ColD

```
table1
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
 A       B       G       F
 G       B       C       F
```

I tried

```
select * from table1 where ColB = ColB and ColD = ColD.
```

Is there anyway I can filter out similar data appear in ColB and ColD using one sql statement?

Comment: Not sure what your question is, and what your required result is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you get from your table data to your desired result? There is no real pattern noticeable, saying that, G B C F should also be in your result, since it is the only one with a G in colA...?

Comment: @JonathanChan, And why do you want ABGF and ABCF, based on what criteria should these be returned? What is the question that you want to ask the database? 'Give me all records which ...', something like that... Else we cannot help you.

Comment: @Najzero oh sorry I have chaneg the desire result. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @Maarten. Sorry shall be ABGF and BGCF the result is filtered base on ColB and ColD

Comment: @JonathanChan, I think you might be thinking of the table as merely a 2-dimensional matrix of values, rather than as a set of rows. `select * from table1 where ColB = ColB and ColD = ColD` will, necessarily, return all rows because, for example, `ColB = ColB` will ALWAYS, logically, be true (ignoring nulls).

Comment: also, how do you get BGCF? Your example data has no rows where `ColA = B` or where `ColB = G`.

Answer (score 4):

"similar columns":

```
select colB, ColD 
from table1 
group by colB, ColD
having count(*) > 1
```

Data that have "simillar columns":

```
select * 
from table1
join (    select colB, ColD 
    from table1 
    group by colB, ColD
    having count(*) > 1
) a on table1.colB = a.colB and table1.colD = a.colD
```

Another approach would be:

```
select * from (
    select 
    s.*,
    count(*) over (partition by colB, ColD) as cnt
    from table1 s
)
where cnt > 1
```